# AngularJs ui doesn't update after crud operations with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to build a simple CRUD app for managing employees tasks with AngularJs 
MongoDb ,and NodeJs. For some reason the scope variables doesn't update when doing CRUD operations, with $http requests from angular to node.

First i get the Tasks list by using :

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:3000/employees-tasks")
    .success(function (response) {
      $scope.arrEmployeesTasks = response;
    });
```

Suppose i want to delete employee's task - i'm using the following functions:

AngularJs:

```
 $scope.deleteTask = function (prmTaskObj) {

  $http.delete("http://localhost:3000/delete-task?_id=" + prmTaskObj._id).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Node Js

```
exports.delete = (req, res) => {

Tasks.findByIdAndRemove(req.query._id)
.then(task => {
    if(!task) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "task not found with id " + req.query._id
        });
    }
    res.send({message: "task deleted successfully!"});
}).catch(err => {
    if(err.kind === 'ObjectId' || err.name === 'NotFound') {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "task not found with id " + req.query._id
        });                
    }
    return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete task with id " + req.query._id
    });
  });
};
```

It's important to add that the CRUD operations works...but i can't get the  $scope.arrEmployeesTasks variable to update accordingly in the UI.

Comment: have you console.log your response? the apps I've worked on, response is usually a wrapper and the result set is hung off of response.data

Comment: The response is just the response type...success or fail..

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs Digest circle not running out side angular scope.force full you have to execute digest circle using $scope.$apply().

Comment: Thanks, where should i use it? can you elaborate?

Comment: By Default when you change any $scope variable in  angularjs internally it run digest circle it check all the scope variable and find which scope variable is changed        and call $watch for watches $scope valriable and update $scope variable which is changed . this circle called digest circle . when if you are working out side of angularjs then digest circle not running. like inside Jquery $ajax method in your case crud operation with node js

Comment: @RoyBarOn if You got  your answer please accept my answer